# Range Bernard lights and open lights light up however the burner to not get hot and the oven does not get hot

Tags: electrical

My  Electric stove top burners on my GE range and he open on my GE range post light up when I turn them on however they do not heat up.

Comment: Hello,  and  welcome  to Stack Exchange. We'll need more information before we can help you, e.g. how  long has this happened? what do you mean by "lights up"? when did this start?

Comment: Have any changes been made in your house recently? Any construction? Any work in your service panel? Is your service panel full and people are moving breakers around to make stuff fit?